# STATIC_URL Not Working After Django 1.5 Upgrade

Tags: django, django-settings, django-staticfiles

Im probably just tired and dont notice something obvious here but after upgrade to Django 1.5 the path to my static files is broken.

settings.py

```
from os.path import abspath, basename, dirname, join, normpath

SITE_ROOT = dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))

SITE_NAME = basename(SITE_ROOT)

PROJECT_ROOT = dirname(SITE_ROOT)

STATIC_ROOT = normpath(join(SITE_ROOT, 'static', 'site_media'))

STATIC_URL = "/site_media/static/"

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
    "staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
    "staticfiles.finders.LegacyAppDirectoriesFinder",
    "compressor.finders.CompressorFinder",
```

)

index.html

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/site_base.css" />
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
{% load static from staticfiles %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/site_base.css' %}" />
```

Documentation for the new implementation of Django 1.5:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#template-tags

Comment: Fantastic. Worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

Because in Django 1.5 you have to use {% load staticfiles %}

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{STATIC_URL}}css/site_base.css" />
```