# How does collect static work?

Tags: django

I don't fundamentally understand how manage.py collectstatic works. The idea I had was you have the path

```
project/app/static/app/base.css
```

and run collectstatic and it copies them to a /staticfiles/ folder which can then be accessed by {{STATIC_URL}}. I've tried this and it doesn't seem to find base.css.

Here are my variables for reference:

```
basepath = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]    
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(basepath, 'staticfiles')
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}base.css" />
```

Which all leads up to a 404 error when trying to get the stylesheet:

```
"GET /base.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2255
```

Comment: is the stylesheet available at `/static/base.css`?

Comment: It seems to be. When I collectstatic it tells me one file is copied, but to where? Here's how my directory looks: http://i.imgur.com/6HmlQZO.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems collectstatic is copying it over fine.

I think you just need to use the `{% static "base.css" %}` template tag instead of trying to access the `STATIC_URL` variable

i don't think `STATIC_URL` is available in the template scope.

you COULD access it doing something like

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.STATIC_URL
```

but `{% static %}` tag does this for you.  It seems the version of django is important 1.5 [looks like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184245/static-url-not-working-after-django-1-5-upgrade) it uses the `{% static %}` tag, but early versions look like they support `STATIC_URL` when you have `RequestContext` registered.

Comment: Worked a treat. I think I read somewhere that this is grossly inefficient for deployment to production? Or am I thinking of something else?

Comment: @Nanor, kind of, your web server, ie. apache, nginx, etc should be serving your static content, not django, if using apache you can use an `Alias` to do this

Comment: If it gets the files from Amazon S3 is that similar to having a web server do it? That's how I've just set it up.

Comment: @Nanor, yes, perhaps even better